# Using entire gpu during realtime inference

Tags: python, opencv, gpu, tensorflow

Im using the following code to do realtime inference from mobilenet

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = '0'

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

camera.set(3, 1280)

camera.set(4, 1024)

# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line
               in tf.gfile.GFile('tf_model/output_labels.txt')]

gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True,per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.9)
sess_config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options, log_device_placement=False,allow_soft_placement = True)
sess_config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.9
sess_config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True


def grabVideoFeed():
    grabbed, frame = camera.read()
    return frame if grabbed else None


def initialSetup():
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        with tf.gfile.FastGFile('tf_model/output_graph.pb', 'rb') as f:
            graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
            tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')


initialSetup()

with tf.Session(config= sess_config) as sess:
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

    while True:
        frame = grabVideoFeed()
        //do the rest of classification
```

Though I have tried to use gpu, it is still not using the entire gpu. gpu usage is only 8%. how can I be able to sort this out?

Comment: Are you doing any batching, or just passing each image as an individual `sess.run`?

Comment: Im passing each frame

Comment: That may be a good start. There is a latency/throughput tradeoff: if you can hold on to some images (ideally enough to fill up your GPU memory) and run inference as a batch, you'll increase GPU utilization and images/second. Keeping a GPU busy can be tricky, so maybe take a look at the [input pipeline performance guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#input_pipeline_optimization) too (granted it's mostly aimed at training).